# Export Markers From Vegas Studio 14?

Tags: vegas-pro

The videos below show how to export markers from v12 and v13, but I don't have the View -> Window -> Edit Details options they're showing in v14.

Anyone know how to do it in v14?

Comment: Movie Studio does not have many of the features that Vegas Pro has. I guess you can't do it in VMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimenting it's clear this is a feature only available in Vegas Pro (Edit or better). Thankfully there is a trial version which I was able to use to confirm this is the case.